# Merge two point clouds with known positions (python, OpenCV) - Transformation

Tags: python, opencv, rotation, transformation, point-clouds

I've two point clouds and the exact positions (coordinates, quaternions). Now I want to transform the second point clouds into the first.

I tried to get the difference of the two coordinates and quaternions and then I've translated the  second coordinates with the difference to the first and the same with a rotation matrix of the quaternions. I can't get a useful outcome.

Is there any function in python / OpenCV that would do that for me automatically?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me want you're trying to do but it sounds like you're looking for [scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html), specifically `align_vectors()`.